# Create ranges from numbers

Tags: ruby, numbers

I have an array of hashes that have numbers:

```
 [
    {
    y: 316.28,
    label: "Kaimur",
    color: "Light_Green"
    },
    {
    y: 323.63,
    label: "Banka",
    color: "Light_Green"
    },
    {
    y: 327.85,
    label: "Gaya",
    color: "Light_Green"
    },
    {
    y: 346.11,
    label: "EastChamparan",
    color: "Light_Green"
    },
    {
    y: 358.38,
    label: "Nalanda",
    color: "Light_Green"
    },
    {
    y: 363.13,
    label: "Madhubani",
    color: "Light_Green"
    }
]
```

Here my first number is `316.28` and last number is `363.13`. I want to created ranges from this array like `300 to 400`. This is an example using the first and the last element of the array.

I want to make it like `300 to 400` or `100 to 200` or `10 to 20`.

If my number is `316.28`, I want to return a value `300` and if my value is `363.13`, then it should return `400`.

How can I do that?

I want to round my values if my list of array has three number 2 numbers or 4 numbers such as `12.5`, `123.45`, or `3900.56`. These can be the number and all of my array can have these kind of numbers. If I have to round each number after finding a length, that becomes a nightmare. I need a function which can do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Float#round`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-round) with a negative argument:

```
316.28.round(-2)
#⇒ 300
363.13.round(-2)
#⇒ 400
```

---

```
input = _
#⇒ [{:y=>316.28, :label=>"Kaimur", :color=>"Light_Green"},
#   {:y=>323.63, :label=>"Banka", :color=>"Light_Green"},
#   {:y=>327.85, :label=>"Gaya", :color=>"Light_Green"},
#   {:y=>346.11, :label=>"EastChamparan", :color=>"Light_Green"},
#   {:y=>358.38, :label=>"Nalanda", :color=>"Light_Green"},
#   {:y=>363.13, :label=>"Madhubani", :color=>"Light_Green"}]
ys = input.map { |e| e[:y] }
#⇒ [316.28, 323.63, 327.85, 346.11, 358.38, 363.13]
Range.new *[ys.min, ys.max].map { |e| e.round(-e.round.to_s.length+1) }
#⇒ 300..400
```

Comment: `*ys.minmax.map {#...}` :)

Comment: `ys = input.map { |e| e[:y] }; [ys.min, ys.max]` can become `input.minmax_by { |e| e[:y] }`..and if I'm not mistaken you can use `Math.log10` to get the *positive* number to round to (you'd still need to make it negative; so like `num.round(-Math.log10(num).to_i)` should work unless I'm derping on my math right now)

Comment: @SimpleLime `minmax_by` would return the whole Hash so you would still need to access `e[:y]` to create the actual Range